# Excel VBA Code for Column Totals

Tags: excel, vba

Quick question

What is the VBA code for summing column data. The sum/total would ideally be in the last row of each column; my e.g is below.

```
**Purchase Value**
 6,578,548.01 
 15,883,286.84 

      -
      -
      -
 45,929,606.02 
 26,446,713.72
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Let us assume your purchase value in column A

```
Sub simple()
    LastRow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Total = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(Range("A2:A" & LastRow))
    Range("A" & LastRow + 1).Value = Total
End Sub
```

do this for rest of the column you have. if columns are long, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

You can find addresses of the first and the last cells with sums in your column, then you add them up. There is a number of ways you can do that, here is one for you:

```
Sub columnSum()

    varSumColumn = Cells.Find(What:="**Purchase Value**", LookAt:=xlWhole).Column
    varColumnFirstRow = Cells.Find(What:="**Purchase Value**", LookAt:=xlWhole).Row + 1
    varColumnLastRow = Cells.Find(What:="**Purchase Value**", LookAt:=xlWhole).End(xlDown).Row
    varColumnSum = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(Range(Cells(varColumnFirstRow, varSumColumn), Cells(varColumnLastRow, varSumColumn)))
    Cells(varColumnLastRow + 1, varSumColumn) = varColumnSum 

End Sub
```

This example find the column with **Purchase Value**, then determines the range of sums and adds them up.
As i said, it's one of several possible methods.

Answer (score 0):

Following code will give sum of all the columns in the sheet. Sum will be displayed below the last row of each column.

```
Sub SumAllColumns()
    lastCol = Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

    For col = 1 To lastCol
        lastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, col).End(xlUp).Row
        colSum = WorksheetFunction.Sum(Range(Cells(2, col), Cells(lastRow, col)))
        Cells(lastrow + 1, col) = colSum
    Next col
End Sub
```